# Same query giving different result in Databricks vs Snowflake

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

The following query gives different result in Snowflake and Databricks.
**Snowflake**:- 766967
**Databricks**:- 749309

​

```
SELECT SUM(ORDER_ID) FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT B.VISITOR_ID,TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CREATE_TS) as CREATE_TS
,B.VISIT_ID
,COUNT( A.ORDER_ID_V32) as ORDER_ID
FROM EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_SHOP A
JOIN EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_OTHER B
ON A.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID = B.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID
JOIN EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_METRICS C
ON A.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID = C.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID
WHERE DATE(B.CREATE_TS)  = '2023-09-08'-- and '2023-09-08'
AND B.DW_CURRENT_VERSION_IND='TRUE' AND C.DW_CURRENT_VERSION_IND='TRUE'
group by B.VISITOR_ID,CREATE_TS,B.VISIT_ID)
```

In databricks I am using the following process to achieve the above result:

```
TEST_Q=(
"""
SELECT SUM(ORDER_ID) FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT B.VISITOR_ID,TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CREATE_TS) as CREATE_TS
,B.VISIT_ID
,COUNT( A.ORDER_ID_V32) as ORDER_ID
FROM EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_SHOP A
JOIN EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_OTHER B
ON A.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID = B.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID
JOIN EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_METRICS C
ON A.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID = C.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID
WHERE DATE(B.CREATE_TS)  = '2023-09-08'
AND B.DW_CURRENT_VERSION_IND='TRUE' AND C.DW_CURRENT_VERSION_IND='TRUE'
group by B.VISITOR_ID,CREATE_TS,B.VISIT_ID)
"""
)
BIMDF2 = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(**db_options).option("query",TEST_Q).load()

display(BIMDF2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well the DISTINCT is pointless inside the sub-select, as you are also doing a GROUP BY operation as well.

thus this is the same SQL:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ORDER_ID) 
FROM (
    SELECT  
        B.VISITOR_ID,
        TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CREATE_TS) as CREATE_TS
        ,B.VISIT_ID
        ,COUNT(A.ORDER_ID_V32) as ORDER_ID
    FROM EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_SHOP as A
    JOIN EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_OTHER as B
        ON A.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID = B.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID
            and AND B.DW_CURRENT_VERSION_IND = 'TRUE'
            and DATE(B.CREATE_TS) = '2023-09-08'
    JOIN EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_METRICS as C
        ON A.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID = C.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID
            AND C.DW_CURRENT_VERSION_IND = 'TRUE'
    group by 1,2,3
)
```

but really you are grouping then summing those counts, (I assume the sum is a "quality check step").

But the post SQL is the same as:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(A.ORDER_ID_V32) as ORDER_ID
FROM EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_SHOP as A
JOIN EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_OTHER as B
    ON A.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID = B.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID
        and AND B.DW_CURRENT_VERSION_IND = 'TRUE'
        and DATE(B.CREATE_TS) = '2023-09-08'
JOIN EDM_VIEWS_QA.DW_VIEWS.CLICK_STREAM_METRICS as C
    ON A.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID = C.CLICK_STREAM_INTEGRATION_ID
        AND C.DW_CURRENT_VERSION_IND = 'TRUE'
```

which implies running the above SQL on both system should give you the same results as the original SQL.

At which point I would be inclined to mistrust the DATA over the SQL engines themselves (but it is an option), and I would run this block again with `C` missing and see if the results are the same, and then skip a `B` JOIN/TABLE, but this might be a much larger query as the date filter is now missing.

But the point being, workout why you have different results, in smaller table A, B, C have x rows, and the base joins all sum the same, step-by-step.